# GCP importing data from csv to cloud sql error

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

I am just taking a csv file and importing it directly into cloud sql through GCP console import and getting an unexpected error.Can you please advise what could be the issue.GCP doesnt show me what that unexpected error is ?

sku name item 
43900 Duracell - AAA Batteries (4-Pack) HardGood
48530 Duracell - AA 1.5V CopperTop Batteries (4-Pack) HardGood
127687 Duracell - AA Batteries (8-Pack) HardGood 
150115 Energizer - MAX Batteries AA (4-Pack) HardGood 
185230 Duracell - C Batteries (4-Pack) HardGood